# How do I make IntelliJ Idea to use license server at startup via proxy

Tags: intellij-idea

My company has provided a license server which is accessible via a proxy server. The problem here is Intellij Idea does not take my system proxy settings at startup. How do i make Intellij access the license server at startup?